# How to create .exe with pyinstaller with code using xgboost

Tags: python, pyinstaller, xgboost

I am using python 3.6.4, pyinstaller 3.4.
My code imports numpy and xgboost.
I wish to create a .exe from the project.

The code below as a ".py" run without any problomes on my machine

```
import xgboost as xgb

import numpy as np

init()

data = np.random.rand(5,10) # 5 entities, each contains 10 features
label = np.random.randint(2, size=5) # binary target
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( data, label=label)

dtest = dtrain

param = {'bst:max_depth':2, 'bst:eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }
param['nthread'] = 4
param['eval_metric'] = 'auc'

evallist  = [(dtest,'eval'), (dtrain,'train')]

num_round = 10
bst = xgb.train( param, dtrain, num_round, evallist )

bst.dump_model('dump.raw.txt')
```

when I convert to exe

## and wiriting to the .spec file the following:

```
datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all("xgboost")
```

exe is creating successfully

but when I run the .exe file I get the following screen:

```
PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies.
Please install PyWin32 or pywin32-ctypes.

pip install pypiwin32
```

any case I do have pypiwin32 install.

## appreciate if someone knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

After a research:

For making an exe using pyinstaller from a script which use xgboost libary:

1.One must first grab the "xgboost.dll" and insert it to a folder name "xgboost" in the dist folder - link:[http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/2016/09/22/xgboost-windows-x64-binaries-for-download/][1]

2. please use the code bellow to get the hidden imports, needed( datas and binaries should be empty in xgboost case)
   `from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all
   datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all("xgboost")`
   and add it to the .spec files.

good luck